# How to convert this inner join in sequelize?

Tags: sequelize.js

*How can i do this query in sequelize*

```
(SELECT rol FROM roles INNER JOIN user_roles ON roles.id = user_roles.roleId)
```

here is my schema

```
sequelize.define('user_roles', {
    userId: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    roleId: Sequelize.INTEGER
  });
```

and role schema

```
sequelize.define('roles', {
  rol: Sequelize.STRING
});
```

and user roles schema

```
sequelize.define('user_roles', {
    userId: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    roleId: Sequelize.INTEGER
  });
```

in user roles i add user id and the role id to make the inner join

Answer (score 1):

```
const UserRole = sequelize.define('UserRole', {
    });

    const User = sequelize.define('User', {
        name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
            required: true
        },
    });

    const Role = sequelize.define("Roles", {
        name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        }
    })

    Role.belongsToMany(User, { through: UserRole })
    User.belongsToMany(Role, { through: UserRole })
```

Then do the query

```
const roles = await Role.findAll({
        include: [
            {
                model: User,
                through: UserRole,
                required: true
            }
        ]
    })
```

An complete running example can be found on [github sscce](https://github.com/ratulSharker/sequelize-sscce/tree/stackoverflow-2). You can clone and run the whole demo. Main source file can be found [here](https://github.com/ratulSharker/sequelize-sscce/blob/stackoverflow-2/src/sscce.js)

Comment: got and  error user_roles is not associated to roles!

Comment: im actually new at this so im really lost

Comment: Same error im doing it like this
        UserRoles.belongsTo(Role, {
          foreignKey: "roleId"
      })
       Role.findAll({
        include: [
            {
                 model: UserRoles
            }
        ]
    })

Comment: I have added an running example, check it out.

Comment: its working the only thing is that it brings all roles but i spected only 2, can i add a where? something like where: {roles.id = user_roles.roleId}

Comment: Did you ran the example i've given ?

Comment: Yes but it returns my 3 roles and i spected 2 roles

Comment: Updated the query portion in the answer added `required: true`.

Comment: There we go you are the master men, thanks a lot. ;P

Comment: Atually i just realiced that it still brings me the 3 roles :/

Comment: You can pull my git example, where i've updated my code, there is two role mainly, but it brings one role, on which the user is connected.

Comment: this code const UserRole = sequelize.define('UserRole', {
    }); is empty what should it have ?

Comment: It is fine to be emtpy, It is the pivot table. Column will be added automatically while association play in action.

Comment: by the way i have a third table call user roles all update question check it out

Comment: Stop procrastinating, If you have any other question, ask it as a separate question.